# How to manually load data in sencha Ext js from API without using "autosync" & "autoLoad: true"?

Tags: javascript, rest, extjs, sencha-cmd

```
Ext.define('EmpMgmt.store.Personnel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.personnel',
    model: 'EmpMgmt.model.Personnel',

fields: [
    { name: 'name' },
    { email: 'email' },
    { phone: 'phone' },
],
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    reader: {
    type: 'json',
    rootProperty: 'data'
},
},
launch: ()=> {
    var yourStore = Ext.getStore('EmpMgmt.store.Personnel'); 
    yourStore.load(); 
},
});
```

I want to load data from API manually but dont know exact way about how to approach it? I am newbie in sencha ext js

Comment: What is launch function here? It won't be invoked unless you are explicitly calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually load your store using the ViewController and ViewModel of it's view. Assuming that you have a view like this:

```
    Ext.define('EmpMgmt.view.Personnel', {
       extend: 'Ext.grid.Grid',
       xtype: 'personnel',
       viewModel: 'personnel',
       bind: '{personnel}', //this config will bind the store from your viewModel
       title: 'Personnel',
       columns: [{
          text: 'Name',
          dataIndex: 'name' //the same name from the Model's configuration
       }, {
          text: 'E-mail',
          dataIndex: 'email' //the same name from the Model's configuration
       }]
    })
```

In your viewModel you can do this:

```
Ext.define('EmpMgmt.view.PersonnelViewModel', {
   extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
   alias: 'viewmodel.personnel',
   stores: {
      personnel: {
         type: 'personnel' //here your store is defined by saying "Hey ViewModel's store I'am a store of type Personnel" the one you created in the example
      }
   }
})
```

And finally your ViewController can load the store manually:

```
Ext.define('EmpMgmt.view.PersonnelViewController', {
       extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
       alias: 'controller.personnel',
       initViewModel: function () { //triggers everytime your application initialize the viewModel, you can use "init" too
          const me = this;
          const viewModel = me.getViewModel();
          const store = viewModel.getStore('personnel');
          store.load();//will load your store at this method load() from ExtJS's Store
       }
    })
```

Despite the code, I strongly recommend you to see more at the sencha's Documentation about [Store](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html), [ViewModel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/modern/Ext.app.ViewModel.html) and [Controller](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/modern/Ext.app.ViewController.html).

If something isn't clear or you have more doubts, don't hesitate to ask!

Hope it helps!

Comment: And this isn't restricted to grid, It could be a form, a combobox. The view I used was just an exemple. The load() method is for the stores.